# winpdb GUI not running

Tags: python, software-installation, gui, gtk

I installed `winpdb` ( a python debugger ) . When I tried to run it's GUI version it showed this error

```
wxPython was not found.
wxPython 2.6 or higher is required to run the winpdb GUI.
wxPython is the graphical user interface toolkit used by Winpdb.
You can find more information on wxPython at http://www.wxpython.org/
The Unicode version of wxPython is recommended for Winpdb.
To use the debugger without a GUI, run rpdb2.
```

After this I installed `wxPython` by doing this `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8` , which installed `wxPython` `2.8` version . But then when I again ran `winpdb` it is showing the same error and `winpdb` GUI is not running . 
Please help me with this .

Answer (score 1):

For install `wxPython` try with :

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxglade python-wxversion python-wxgtk2.8 pyprompter python-pythoncard python-squaremap python-wxgtk2.8-dbg python-wxmpl python-wxtools pythoncard pythoncard-doc pythoncard-tools
```